# Minimal Ubuntu-Studio Requirements

Tags: ubuntu-studio

I use Ubuntu-Studio 18.04.1 LTS and I guess there should be some minimal requeriments for this. But, I cannot to find them...

Some idea about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from the [Audio Handbook](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/AudioHandbook/GettingStarted#System_Requirements)

```
System Requirements
Before running the installation, you might want to check that your computer has the minimum requirements.

• 2 GHz dual core processor
• 2 GB RAM (system memory)
• 25 GB hard-drive space (Ubuntu Studio's footprint is much smaller, but you'll need extra space)
• VGA monitor capable of 1024x768 resolution
• Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port to install and try out the operating system
```